# Using key function without overwritting the same keys in PHP

Tags: php, key

I'd like to extract the data from an array within an array. But the problem is, when I use the key function it overwrites the first entry. I'm expecting to have a result of 135 rows, but it only gives me back 114.

Below is the code where I'm getting a problem..

```
while($row1 = mssql_fetch_array($result1)) {
        $mycount = $mycount + 1;
        $boskey = $row1["EAN11"]."^".$row1["AUART"];
        $boskey1 = $row1["ORDNUM"]."^".$row1["ERDAT"]."^".$row1["KUNAG"]."^".$row1["NAME1"]."^".$row1["PERNR"]."^".$row1["FKIMG"]."^".$row1["BASEPRICE"]."^".$row1["NETPRICE"]."^".$row1["ZZMAXDISC"]."^".$row1["MVGR1"]."^".$row1["KDGRP"];
        $bos[$boskey][$boskey1] = $bos[$boskey][$boskey1];

    }

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($bos); $i++) {
            $abc = key($bos);   

            $arr = explode("^",$abc);
            $ean11 = $arr[0];
            $auart = $arr[1];

            echo $ean11 . " - " . $auart;

            for ($j = 0; $j < count($bos[$abc]); $j++) { //total count of $bos[$abc] is 114.
                $xxx = key($bos[$abc]);
                $arr1 = explode("^",$xxx);

                $ordnum = $arr1[0];
                $docdate = $arr1[1];
                $customer = $arr1[2];
                $name1 = $arr1[3];
                $ae = $arr1[4];
                $qty = $arr1[5];
                $baseprice = $arr1[6];
                $netprice = $arr1[7];
                //$discount = $arr1[8];
                $booktype = $arr1[9];
                $kdgrp = $arr1[10];
                $discount = 100 - (100 * ( $netprice / $baseprice));
```

Comment: Why do you use a for_loop? How about trying the foreach loop and see what happens? - $bos[$boskey][$boskey1] = $bos[$boskey][$boskey1]; -
Why do you assign something to itself?

Comment: @Touch is I'dont know why did the developer wrote that line. This is an existing program, I was just assigned to debug because some data were not shown. Sorry. I'm still in learning php..

Comment: It's 3 in the morning for me so I got to sleep. If your question is still not answered in a matter of hours, perhaps I'll check on it again. This code is a little confusing. And try adding the $row variables so we can get a bigger picture of what is going on there.

Comment: @Touch adding the $row variables?.. what Im showing here is a table. elements are categorized..for example, fruit table, inside fruit are apples, mango, grapes. Then next table would be vegetables. but the problem is, for example I have a star-apple and this would be on the first table right? instead, it the apple on the first table would be replace by the star-apple. something like that sir..